# Overloading ofstream produces two different results

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, ofstream, overloading

I have overloaded the ofstream operator in one particular file, cfileop.cpp, as such:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ofs, LPCWSTR wideString)
{
    //ofs << ConvertUnicodeToUtf8(wideString).GetBuffer();
    ofs << CW2A(wideString,CP_UTF8);
    return ofs;
}
```

In this particular file, any call being made using the operator works perfect. I have no problems at all.

However, I need to overload this same operator in another file. When I repeat this call in another location, acrazyapp.cpp, I get something like this output:

```
02962AE010021A3402961018
029621C010021A3410022AF0
029621C010021A34029619D0
029621C010021A3410022A68
```

Which, I thought, could be solved simply by switching the location of the overload to acrazyapp.cpp. This, however, caused cfileop.cpp not to properly output. In an attempt to satisfy both, I moved the call to a header file, ch_ofstream.h, and included it in both cpp files. However, in this case, I received this error: fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found.

How can I ensure that the ofstream operator above is properly overloaded in both cpp files without combining the cpp files?

Thank you!

Comment: Declaring it in a header used by both and linking the two cpps should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the overload is not declared in that other file, you end up calling `operator<<(void*)`, which prints the address that the pointer points to.

As with any other function, you should declare it in one header file, and implement in one source file.

Comment: Actually, with the above, I simply forgot to have a true declaration in my header file and include it in both. With that, I was able to fix everything. You made me look into it again to confirm and I realized my mistake - such a rookie mistake at that! Thanks!